# How can I load chunks without circling around the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to load non-existing chunks without a player traveling?

I am asking this because everyone know that worldGen causes a ton of lag in server world, and I don't want to circle around the map just to form the chunks. So I want to know if there is any way to load these chunks without player intervention.

Comment: Hi, HoTag, welcome to Arqade!  I've reworded your question so that it doesn't require mods or tools to answer it; any sort of solution is now valid.

Comment: modded or unmodded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pre-generate a Minecraft world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32316/how-do-i-pre-generate-a-minecraft-world)

Comment: The duplicate seems to be asking for a one-time usage sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a bukkit server you could use the ChunkPrequote plugin.
This plugin will automatically generate chunks for you without having to fly around.
[Download Chunk Prequote Here](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/chunkprequote/)
Chunk Prequote is a 1.6.4 plugin so you wouldn't be able to do this yet with a 1.7 server.

Another solution could be to just limit the size of the world. This will make it so chunks will eventually run out and there will be no more server lag from newly generated chunks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It may still work on a 1.7 server, I'm a bucket plugin dev and usually plugins for older versions still work with newer versions of the server

Answer (score 0):

Well if you go in a 1.8 version of Minecraft you can use a command block mod/helper know that once started you give it like 20min and it will tp you all around your world in a big square generating/loading in a 10000x10000 block area.