# Is there any way to pre-generate chunks in an already existing minecraft server world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friends have been playing on a modded minecraft server running the All The Mods 6 modpack. We've been playing for a while and recently started running into performance issues. The server has 12GB of ram and 6 Xeon CPU cores so that shouldn't be the issue. I thought it might have been because of the amount of chunks we're generating, especially in the end. Is there any way to use a chunk pre-generator mod to generate chunks in a pre-existing world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pre-generate a Minecraft world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32316/how-do-i-pre-generate-a-minecraft-world)